# equirectangular panorama rendering?

Tags: opengl, rendering, glsl, camera, fragment-shader

I want to render my scenes as equirectangular panorama frames.

I can get the angular fisheye which is what I actually need by applying the rendered frame as a texture to a correctly UV mapped circle.

But how can the scene be rendered as equirectangular panorama?

I'm using a 3d engine which uses OpenGL and GLSL.

Comment: Seems like you'd need a 360° horizontal field of view, and a 180° vertical field of view. But I'm not sure how to construct that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to render your scene into a cube map, then render a quad. The texture coordinates would then translate directly to longitude/latitude you can use to calculate the vector to use for sampling the cube map.

For equirectangular projection:

```
lon = u*2*pi
lat = (v*2-1)*2*pi

x = cos(lon)*cos(lat)
y = sin(lon)*cos(lat)
z = sin(lat)
```

Where u/v are the texture coordinates of the quad.